# Engine making weird noise at specific RPM range

Tags: engine, noise, kia

The car in question is 2017 Kia Ceed with 1.6 GDI petrol engine.

Lately, I noticed a wierd noise coming out of the engine. As I'm accelerating, up to around 3200-3300 RPM everything sounds fine. Above 4000 RPM the engine also sounds fine.

However, in between those 2, at 3300-4000 RPM roughly, engine sounds like, for a lack of better word, "gurgling" or like I have a V8 in there.

Also, I have noticed the car is lacking power in the higher RPM ranges compared to what it felt before.

It was serviced 2 months ago at the dealership, so if anything, this proably is a recent fault.

I tried checking if it's maybe a hole in the exhaust system, but couldn't locate any.

What else could be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

Once every one or two years, my car needs nozzle cleaning. It loses power and vibrations appear.

The best way is cleaning without removing nozzles and replacing spark plugs after it.

Answer (score -1):

check you mechanical advancer weights that will only advance at certain rpm. the spring may be
stretched or the tiny plastic bushing may be broken.

Comment: While not a bad suggestion, I doubt it has any bearing on the OP's situation. Considering the age of the vehicle, I doubt it has a distributor ... at least that's what it seems you're getting at. The ignition system in a '17 Kia is going to be completely electronic. Advance would all be done via the ECU.